# debugging zsh completion method

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, debugging

I am trying to debug a completion method. This method is supposed to present with all the directories within these three folders. I verified that compinit is loading it correctly. tried tracing and i can't decypher most of it.

here is my completion function

```
#compdef c

_files -W $PROJECT/repos -/
_files -W $PROJECT/helm -/
_files -W ~/Code -/
```

and the function itself, c

```
#!/bin/zsh

cd "$PROJECTS/$1"
```

I don't get anything, nothing. And i can't figure out how to debug it to figure out whats being put in _files to begin with.

Answer (score 14):

Press `^X?` (<kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> <kbd>?</kbd>) instead of <kbd>Tab</kbd> to run [`_complete_debug`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fcomplete_005fdebug-_0028_005eX_003f_0029). This places a trace of the completion code into a file which you can view by pressing <kbd>Up</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

---

Alternatively, if you want to generate a trace of a specific function while you're debugging it, add this to the beginning of your function to get an execution trace:

```
setopt local_options xtrace
```

The trace is extremely verbose so you may prefer to have it in a file rather than on the terminal. To do that, put the code in an auxiliary function and redirect that function's stderr.

```
#compdef c

function _c_do_complete {
  _files -W $PROJECT/repos -/
  _files -W $PROJECT/helm -/
  _files -W ~/Code -/
}

function _c {
  setopt local_options xtrace
  _c_do_complete 2>|~/_c.trace
}

_c "$@"
```

---

You have `$PROJECT` in the completion code but `$PROJECTS` in the function (which is actually a script, which would do nothing since `cd` alone in a script is pointless.) Other than that, your code looks sensible to me.

Comment: i ran functions -t _c and got the trace, problem is its so verbose i can't make heads or tails what its doing.   looks like the _files is a lamda, not a list of values. and $PROJECT is an evironment var

Comment: @scphantm Yes, sure, `_files` is a function and `$PROJECT` requires `PROJECT` to be a shell variable (not necessarily an environment variable). What did you expect them to be? The trace is large, yes. I've never heard of a higher-level tool to debug completions.

Comment: i fixed my var names and tried as you suggested, no change.  Whats supposed to happen is my autocomplete be filled with the subdirs of those three dirs.

Comment: and yea, i know my c function has a path bug in it, but for the moment id be happy filling the autocomplete.

Comment: @scphantm Your code works for me. I don't see an obvious dependency on configuration options. Does it work with a `.zshrc` that contains nothing apart from `autoload compinit; compinit`?

Comment: could this be a permission thing?  i have to do the compinit with -u to bypass the security check because the folders in question are mapped in by docker and always have a 0777, the standard compini complained about security errors.  could that cause this?

Comment: @scphantm If the completion function gets executed, I don't think there can be a permission problem later.